# Time derivate of expected value

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, expected-value

I have a dynamical system $\dot x(t) = f(x(t))$ with state $x(t)$ taking values in $R^n$ ($t$ is time here).
I'm considering the case in which $x(t)$ is a RV with time-dependent PDF $\rho(x,t)$.
For a smooth test function $\psi(x)$ with compact support, we look at the expectation $\mu(t) := \int_{R^n} \psi(x) \rho(x,t) dx$.
[At the beginning of Section 2 of this paper](http://php.math.unifi.it/users/cimeCourses/2010/02/201022-Notes.pdf), the author derives the equation of continuity (the Liouville PDE) via the following consideration.

On the one hand, the time derivative $\dot \mu(t)$ can be expressed as $\int_{R^n} \psi(x) \frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial t} dx$ (OK, Leibniz rule). On the other, noticing that $\frac{d \psi(x(t))}{dt} = \frac{\partial \psi(x(t))}{\partial x} f(x(t))$ (OK, chain rule), we can also write
$$\dot \mu(t) = 
\int_{R^n} \frac{d \psi(x(t))}{dt} \rho(x,t) dx =
\int_{R^n} \frac{\partial \psi(x(t))}{\partial x} f(x(t)) \rho(x,t) dx.$$

I don't fully see why the first equality in the latter equation must hold. Any hint on how to prove it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Integration by parts and compact support of the test function

Comment: Sorry, why would that apply to the first equality? I see how I could use that to further elaborate the RHS in the equation above, but I don't see why it justifies that expression for the time derivative of the expectation. Thank you.

Comment: You wrote the derivative of the expectation as an integral of psi times the derivative of rho, so using integration by parts you can "move" the derivative from rho to psi, that is the first equality of the latter equation. The second equality follows from your second remark on the chain rule.

Comment: Sorry, I'm slow: how can you use integration by parts in the "integral of psi times the derivative of rho" if the derivative of rho is wrt time and the integral is wrt to $x$?